# Wordpress Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator add thumbnail from video to post

Tags: php, wordpress, video, generator, embed

How can I add a video thumbnail to the post generated by the Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator plugin in Wordpress?

It is a thumbnail of the movie added from the file, not from the YT site, etc. The plugin generates thumbnails from such files, but does not add them to the entries.

Is there any solution to this problem, or the code that would download the thumbnail and paste it into the post?

Answer (score 0):

Please read: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/288434/how-to-change-thumbnail-of-embedded-youtube-video

This might give you an alternative way of implementing the thing you want to accomplish (without using a plugin even).